# Can we convert links only answers into comments for this question?

Tags: discussion

I am just tired of foobar examples as I don't understand them at all, hence they increase my confusions of the topic, so I queried why people use it in examples. Thus I came across this question  with most questions as link only.

I am quiet surprised as accepted answer which is a link only answer has 50 up votes, ermmm so people went to the link to read it and then they up-voted the question - hard to swallow.

[What does 'foo' really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53609/what-does-foo-really-mean)

**Can we convert link only answers specially the accepted one into comment ?**

If it was just 1 post, I would had edited it, but there are tens of them...

Comment: The question is from 2008 and should be closed anyways as it's no longer considered a valid question for SO. Converting 6 year old answers to comments is not exactly useful; I'd just close it and leave it be. Maybe a mod can add a historical lock as well.

Comment: Yes, but would closing the question going to help people who are searching for the meaning of foobar or the site ?

Comment: Of course closing helps, it tells people that these kinds of questions are not welcome on SO. Leaving it open tells people "this is a good question". Even better would be a historical lock, which explicitly describes that the question _was_ considered on-topic once but isn't anymore.

Comment: I agree, but answers still needs improvement

Comment: Actually _improving_ the answers would mean editing them to be valuable, not converting them to comments (outright deletion would be better for the ones that can't be edited into shape). I don't think the effort required to edit the answers would be worth it, given that both the question and any potential answers are not really valuable from a programming perspective.